# How Do I know if my PHP uses Autoloader or not?

Tags: php

I was trying to Use a PHP class, and in the instructions to use it was mentioned separately for "PHP with autoloading enabled" and "PHP w/o Autoloading".

How Do I know if my version of PHP which is 5.4+ uses Autoloading or not ?

Comment: Did you try `echo phpinfo()`?

Comment: @wallyk As far as I understood OP wants to know if autoloading is enabled and if not include another script manually on run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can read about [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

To find out if your framework or set of classes use autoload you can search for: [__autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) or [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Or just search for `_autoload` to find both mentions.

Answer (score 1):

Search your code base for `__autoload`. If you find anything you are using (or your framework is) auto-loading, otherwise you are not.

Comment: What if script uses custom loader? OP should search for `spl_autoload_register`.

Comment: I think OP should search `_autoload`. I this case he will find both `__autoload` and `spl_autoload_register`.